# How I can get all rows with booleanField equal to false?

Tags: python, django, boolean

I am trying to return all the rows with BooleanField equal `true` or `false`.
I am using python django, the field name and field value store in dict:

```
books = Book.objects.filter(**book_dict).prefetch_related(prefetch).select_related(
    'book_pdf',                                                                                              
    'book__pdf_file').distinct('id')
```

The dict contains: `{'fieldName__in': 'False'}`
and the actual query it always 'select ... where fieldName in (True)'
I tryed to change the dict to: `{'fieldName__in': 'false'}` and got the same result, and also change to:`{'fieldName__in': False}` and got error: "bool is not iterable"

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand why you're using `__in`, or why you're using a string for the value. It should just be: `{'fieldname': False}` with no quotes.